# How can I create an object against an object with id

Tags: django

so I would like to create an object against an object. for example. I want to create a 'ticket' which can only be made once there is a 'lead' created. Therefore they have one to many relationship. One lead can have many tickets. Although the tickets are being created against the lead but I cant manage it to do via template.

below is the code.

models.py

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    lead_title  = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    agent_id    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    .......


class Ticket(models.Model):
    lead   = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    passenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    .......
```

views.py

```
def detail_lead(request, id): 
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
    ticket = lead.ticket_set.all()

    context = {

        'lead' : lead,
        'ticket' : ticket,

    }

    return render(request, 'lead/detail_lead.html', context)

def create_ticket(request, id):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Ticket_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form)
            return redirect('lead:listlead')
    else:
        form = Ticket_form()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'ticket/create_ticket.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
path('detaillead/<int:id>', detail_lead, name="detaillead"),
.....
path('createticket/<int:id>/', create_ticket, name="createticket"),
```

detail_lead.html

```
<a href="{% url 'createticket' lead.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add
                      Ticket</button></a>
```

So the detail_lead.html has a button for "Add Ticket" which goes to the add ticket page but once I create the ticket it does not create the ticket against this particular current lead. and when I see in the admin page and look up for the created ticket it has not selected any "lead".

What am I doing wrong here. I want to create a ticket only against this current lead. I know I have to pass the id of a lead into an "a" tag but its still not happening. What am I doing wrong here?

Than you in advance

Comment: can you also show the create_ticket method

Comment: here Ive edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id you are sending from here "{% url 'createticket' lead.id %}" is the lead id, but why are you using that to find a ticket? What is the purpose of finding a ticket by id when you are going to create one anyway?

Use that id to find the Lead and once the ticket has been created, make the relationship between the ticket and the lead.

So it should be

```
lead = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
....
..... 
if form.is_valid():
    item = form.instance
    item.save()
    lead.ticket_set.add(item)
    lead.save()
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships

Comment: Also you need a form to collect the ticket information in your html.

Comment: Perfect :D. After a long run, managed to make this run to what you have said. Thanks