# RegisterForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django, django-custom-user

So I'm making a custom user model. This is what I'am following [Here](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/). I have been pretty much following the tutorial but still I cant make it done.

Error: **RegisterForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'.**

here's my code.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import User

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email   = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)

        widgets = {

                'email' : forms.EmailInput(
                    attrs={'class':'form-control', 'place_holder': '', }),

                'password' : forms.PasswordInput(
                    attrs={'class':'form-control' }),

                    }



class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None, is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_admin=False):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an full name')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.full_name = full_name
        user.set_password(password)
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
        user.active = is_active
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.full_name = full_name
        user.set_password(password)
        user.full_name = full_name
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    active                  = models.BooleanField(default=True) # to login
    staff                   = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin                   = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    created_date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name'] # Email & Password are required by default.

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):         
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True


    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active

class Account_type(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True) 

class Profile(models.Model):
    user                    = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_type            = models.ForeignKey(Account_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

register.html

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm

# Create your views here.

def RegisterForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()        
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

The view logic is simple as you can see. Just saving up the request into the database. The tutorial itself did not tell anything about the view for login and register.

So, What am I doing wrong here.
Thank you

Comment: The view has the same name as your form, hence you "overwrite" the reference to the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your view `RegisterForm` has the same name as your form, hence if you call `RegisterForm` in your view, it will resolve to the view function, and make a recursive call.

Normally (top-level) functions are written in *`snake_case`*, hence you can rewrite it to `register_form`, or even better `register` (since it is not a form at all):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm

# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

Normally a *successful* POST request results in a *redirect* to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). So I strongly advise you to use [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and replace *`some-view-name`* with the name of a view to which you want to redirect.

Comment: Fantastic, never noticed that. and thank you for extra tips. Loved it

Comment: also I have one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836208/how-can-i-create-an-object-against-an-object-with-id If you can have a look. thank you

Comment: Yes. This answer is useful for me. Never noticed that